# How to prove that a real hypersurface in complex space is a smooth manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

We'll use the following definition for **real hypersurface**.

> A (smooth) real hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^N$ is a subset $M$ such that for every point $p_0$ there is a neighborhood $U$ around that point in $\mathbb{C}^N$ and a smooth real-valued function $\rho: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$ M \cap U = \{z \in U : \rho(z, \overline{z}) = 0\} $$
> with differential $d\rho$ nonvanishing in $U$.

Is this guaranteed to be a real smooth manifold? If so, how can we construct the charts and prove that they form a smooth structure from this definition? It seems like we'd like to use these $\{U\}$ for the coordinate neighborhoods, but I don't see how we get a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$.

Comment: Do you know the Constant Rank Theorem in differential topology? Or the implicit function theorem?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the constant rank theorem. I know the implicit function theorem.

Comment: This should be a part of your toolkit when you work with smooth manifolds. See for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508104/rank-theorem-on-manifolds).

Comment: Thank you for these references. Would you mind explaining a bit more about how this is applicable to the above definition of a real hypersurface?